# How to combine image-upload and face-detection in JS

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a project that will detect faces in an image when uploaded. I can upload an image, and I can detect faces in an image. Now I want to combine those two methods. My project can be found [here](http://github.com/adigeefe/Facedetector/tree/master/v0.3) on github.
So far it can detect faces.

Code for uploading images:

```
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$("#imgInp").change(function(){
    readURL(this);
});
 <div id="container">

      <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" class="image"/>
    </div>
```

Code for detecting faces:

```
      <img id="blah" src="photos/1.png" alt="your image" class="image"/>

$('#blah').faceDetection({
      complete : function(faces){

    for (var i = 0; i < faces.length; i++) {
        $("<div>", {
          class : "face",
          css : {
            left : faces[i].x * faces[i].scaleX + "px",
            top : faces[i].y * faces[i].scaleY + "px",
            width : faces[i].width * faces[i].scaleX + "px",
            height : faces[i].height * faces[i].scaleX + "px",

          }

        }).insertAfter(this);
      }},
      error : function(code, message){}
    });
```

Comment: If you think you can create face recognition technology with javascript then your sorely mistaken

Comment: İt just a project for improving myself on JS